# Jenkins Parameterized Remote Trigger Plugin error"JSONArray[0] is not a JSONObject."

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

I am trying to trigger my automation test build from Dev build as downstream using the Jenkins plugin "Parameterized remote trigger"

Set up:

- I have the automation builds on a different host machine
- Automation host machine doesn't run Jenkins as Windows service, instead it is run through cmd java -jar jenkins.war (I require this to get display access, the check box in the service option doesn't do what I require)

Error I see on the Dev build job:

***Even if I get the below error, the automation build gets triggered.***

```
FATAL: JSONArray[0] is not a JSONObject.
net.sf.json.JSONException: JSONArray[0] is not a JSONObject.
    at net.sf.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:1977)
    at 

org.jenkinsci.plugins.ParameterizedRemoteTrigger.RemoteBuildConfiguration.perform(RemoteBuildConfiguration.java:563)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:770)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:533)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1754)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
```

Things tried:

I tried to start jenkins as a windows service I do not get that error, but my automation build fails due to no access to display(for webdriver-manager start).

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30962

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22325

any help will be appreciated.